# Position relative is not working when a master page is including in a aspx page

Tags: css

This is my master page code...........

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.master.cs" Inherits="AP5.MasterPage.Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
     <link href="../css/fonticon-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../css/vendors/nanoscroller/nanoscroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">






    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div class="body-inner nano">
            <div class="nano-content">
                <!--Main Nav container -->
                <aside id="sidebar">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </aside>
                <div id="page">
                    <header id="header" class="hidden-md hidden-small">
                        <div class="container">

                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="../Js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Js/nanoscroller/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css which is creating problem ....

```
.nano {
  position : relative;
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
  overflow : hidden;
}

.nano > .nano-content {
  position      : absolute;
  overflow      : scroll;
  overflow-x    : hidden;
  top           : 0;
  right         : 0;
  bottom        : 0;
  left          : 0;
}
```

When I am making a aspx page including this master page, the master page in not showing the page content. But when I remove relative property from nano class the content is showing but nano scroller is creating a horizontal scroll bar in the page and I want to remove this scroll bar with showing all page content. I use all css and js files properly. Even a text is also not showing in aspx page. But it is working nice in a normal html page. Through master page it is not working properly. Either content is not showing or scroll bar is showing horizontally or nano scroll bar is not working.

Anybody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the css technique you using on your absolute positioned "nano-content" doesn't work if you don't add `margin:auto`. that may be your problem